# Wondering the best way to implement a score function to my anagrams game using OOP in Python

Tags: python, oop, python-class

I am trying to implement an anagram game in python. It currently gives the player 7 tiles from a "Scrabble Bag". I want to add some type of scoring function but I am struggling on

1. Should I implement a score function in one of the classes? or in a def score() function under main... and
2. If i make a function under main how do I retrieve and edit data in the "Bag" class since it returns object at  instead of something such as the letters in a players "hand" (or tiles they posses)

```
import random
N = 7


class Tile:
    def __init__(self, letter, value):
        self.letter = letter
        self.value = value

    def show(self):
        print(f"{self.letter} : {self.value}")

class Bag:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tiles = []
        self.build()

    def build(self):

        templist = {"A": [1, 9],
        "B": [3, 2], 
        "C": [3, 2],
        "D": [2, 4],
        "E": [1, 12],
        "F": [4, 2],
        "G": [2, 3],
        "H": [4, 2],
        "I": [1, 9],
        "J": [8, 1],
        "K": [5, 1],
        "L": [1, 4],
        "M": [3, 2],
        "N": [1, 6],
        "O": [1, 8],
        "P": [3, 2],
        "Q": [10, 1],
        "R": [1, 6],
        "S": [1, 4],
        "T": [1, 6],
        "U": [1, 4],
        "V": [4, 2],
        "W": [4, 2],
        "X": [8, 1],
        "Y": [4, 2],
        "Z": [10, 1],
        }

        for key in templist:
            for i in range(templist[key][1]):
                self.tiles.append(Tile(key, templist[key][0]))
        
    def show(self):
        for tile in self.tiles:
            tile.show()

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.tiles)

    def drawTile(self):
        return self.tiles.pop()
    
    def returnTile(self):
        ...
            

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hand = []

    def draw(self, bag):
        for i in range(7):
            self.hand.append(bag.drawTile())
        return self

    def showHand(self):
        for tile in self.hand:
            tile.show()
    
    def scoreHand(self, play):
        for tile in self.showHand():
            print(tile)
    
def main():
    bag = Bag()
    bag.shuffle()

    p1 = Player("p1")
    p1.draw(bag)
    p1.showHand()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am struggling with using classes as it is relatively new to me, I am not understanding how to retrieve data such as the player hand to use in main, I only can "print" it using my showHand function.

I want to be able to compare a users play from input to characters in the hand to make sure it is a "valid play" but I am missing some pieces in order to get a string of characters to compare the two. When I call the hand from the class it is giving me locations in memory rather than tile objects

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the score you want to compute is the current value of the tiles in a particular Player's hand.  You mention the need to access an instance of Bag.  I don't see where this is necessary or desirable.  Once you have built up a Player with a hand, you only need to work with that instance of Player.

The current score of a Player's hand is an attribute specific to that Player, so it makes perfect sense to add a `scoreHand()` method to your `Player` class:

```
class Player:
    ...
    def scoreHand(self):
        return sum([tile.value for tile in self.hand])
```

If you want to perform operations on a Player's tiles outside of the logic for the class, you can add one or more methods to Player to provide whatever it is that you want to extract from a Player instance.  Given that your Tile class is a public top-level class, you could have a method that returns the list of Tiles for the Player:

```
class Player:
    ...
    def getTiles(self):
        return self.hand
```

If instead, you wanted just the names/letters of a Player's tiles, you could return a list of strings:

```
class Player:
    ...
    def getLetters(self):
        return [tile.letter for tile in self.hand]
```

Comment: This is a great explanation. Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help.  Please upvote and hit the checkmark if this answered your question.